# Integrating numerical data with scipy

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, numerical-integration

Basically I have 2 arrays obtained from a set of data points one array for the x values and one for the y values. I need to numerically integrate the y values with respect to the x values - i.e. an element from the y integrated with respect to the corresponding element in x. This should then generate a new array of elements. I have tried simpson's rule but I get one value back instead of an array. A general idea or approach is all I'm looking for. Any help, however, will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How about using https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.simps.html#scipy.integrate.simps or something else from https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html

Comment: integrate.cumtrapz worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# check out this:
def integration_by_simpsons_3_8_th_rule(i,X,Y,Fd):
   h = X[i]-X[i-1]
   y_n = Y[i]
   y_n_1 = signal[i-1]
   y_n_2 = signal[i-2]
   y_n_3 = signal[i-3]
   Area = (3/8)*h*( y_n_3 + 3*(y_n_2 + y_n_1) + y_n )
   return (X[i-1],Area)

def rolling_integration(X,Y,Fd):
    Y_int = []
    corres_X = []
    for i in range(3,len(signal),1):
        x,y = integration_by_simpsons_3_8_th_rule(i,X,Y,Fd)
        Y_int.append(float(y))
        corres_X.append(float(x))
    return (np.array(corres_X)+(np.array(1/(4*float(Fd)))),np.array(Y_int))

#Fd : for phase correction
```